# how can I get an element in a redirect url using node.js

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, request, api-design

Non-English country, please forgive my spelling mistakes.

For example, I want to first redirect url1(`http://localhost:3000/api/song/167278`) to url2(`http://localhost:4000/api/song/167278`) to use url2's api. And url2 will reponse a json file, which can be seen in the postman's panel.

([postman's pannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdaHD.jpg))

But there maybe a lot of elements, I only want an element in the file, such as `data[0].url`. How can I return just return the **url value** (`data[0].url` in this json) when people access `http://localhost:3000/api/song/167278`.

I am using express.js now, how can I edit it? Or is there any other methods?

```
app.get('api/song/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params
    url = "http://localhost:4000/api/song/" + id
    res.redirect(url)
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Update the question what you want exactly so that we can easily help you

Comment: You could either [proxy](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy) the entire request there or fetch `localhost:4000/api/song/1` in your request handler (with something like node-fetch or axios or with [node's APIs](https://nodejs.dev/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) and send the fields that you want back to the client as json.

Comment: @cubrr Thanks, bro. I use fetch to get the fields. Write an answer and I adopt it.

Comment: Sure thing! I'm glad I could help!

Comment: I have troubled in it for 5 hours. And I got the solution within 3 hours after post in Stack Overflow. Happy! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either [proxy](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy) the entire request there or fetch `localhost:4000/api/song/1` in your request handler (with something like node-fetch or axios or with [node's APIs](https://nodejs.dev/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) and send the fields that you want back to the client as json.